# comparing array value with previous array value

Tags: php

how do I compare the current array value with previous array value.. Example if I have the following array and want to compare [BM1367    PD  C  70][ST00576]['transferfrom'] with previous array which is [BM1367    PD  B  85][ST00576]['transferfrom'] ?

```
    [BM1367    PD  B  85] => Array
        (
            [ST00576] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [transferfrom] => 102
                    [transferto] => 66
                    [BR_ID] => 102
                    [refno] =>  

                )

            [OT01606] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [transferfrom] => 102
                    [transferto] => 66
                    [BR_ID] => 66
                    [refno] => 102 - ST00576

                )

        )

    [BM1367    PD  C  70] => Array
        (
            [ST00576] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [transferfrom] => 102
                    [transferto] => 66
                    [BR_ID] => 102
                    [refno] =>  

                )

            [OT01606] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [transferfrom] => 102
                    [transferto] => 66
                    [BR_ID] => 66
                    [refno] => 102 - ST00576

                )

        )

    [BM1367    PD  C  85] => Array
        (
            [ST00576] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [transferfrom] => 102
                    [transferto] => 66
                    [BR_ID] => 102
                    [refno] =>  

                )

            [OT01606] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [transferfrom] => 102
                    [transferto] => 66
                    [BR_ID] => 66
                    [refno] => 102 - ST00576

                )

        )

    [BM1367    PD  D  85] => Array
        (
            [ST00576] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [transferfrom] => 102
                    [transferto] => 66
                    [BR_ID] => 102
                    [refno] =>  

                )

            [OT01606] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [transferfrom] => 102
                    [transferto] => 66
                    [BR_ID] => 66
                    [refno] => 102 - ST00576

                )

        )

)
```

Comment: I've tried : 

            foreach($transfer as $docno => $transfer_details){
                    
                    //do stuff here
            }

            $previous_br = current(array_map('pick_transferfrom', $transfer));
 }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You asked:

> how do I compare the current array value with previous array value

I think you may want to look at the following PHP functions

1. current() - http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.current.php
2. prev() - http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.prev.php
3. next() - http://php.net/manual/en/function.next.php

For example:

```
<?php
$transport = array('foot', 'bike', 'car', 'plane');
$mode = current($transport); // $mode = 'foot';
$mode = next($transport);    // $mode = 'bike';
$mode = next($transport);    // $mode = 'car';
$mode = prev($transport);    // $mode = 'bike';
$mode = end($transport);     // $mode = 'plane';
?>
```

I was able to use those on a computation formula, work's great! It is also useful when comparing current from previous or next array on yours.

Answer (score 0):

You have an array of `STD class objects` in this case you can compare elements as follows:
Suppose the array which you provided is inside another array

```
$tempArray = {


        [BM1367    PD  B  85] => Array
            (
                [ST00576] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [transferfrom] => 102
                        [transferto] => 66
                        [BR_ID] => 102
                        [refno] =>  

                    )

                [OT01606] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [transferfrom] => 102
                        [transferto] => 66
                        [BR_ID] => 66
                        [refno] => 102 - ST00576

                    )

            )

        [BM1367    PD  C  70] => Array
            (
                [ST00576] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [transferfrom] => 102
                        [transferto] => 66
                        [BR_ID] => 102
                        [refno] =>  

                    )

                [OT01606] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [transferfrom] => 102
                        [transferto] => 66
                        [BR_ID] => 66
                        [refno] => 102 - ST00576

                    )

            )

        [BM1367    PD  C  85] => Array
            (
                [ST00576] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [transferfrom] => 102
                        [transferto] => 66
                        [BR_ID] => 102
                        [refno] =>  

                    )

                [OT01606] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [transferfrom] => 102
                        [transferto] => 66
                        [BR_ID] => 66
                        [refno] => 102 - ST00576

                    )

            )

        [BM1367    PD  D  85] => Array
            (
                [ST00576] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [transferfrom] => 102
                        [transferto] => 66
                        [BR_ID] => 102
                        [refno] =>  

                    )

                [OT01606] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [transferfrom] => 102
                        [transferto] => 66
                        [BR_ID] => 66
                        [refno] => 102 - ST00576

                    )

            )

    )

};
```

You can now access elements as

```
$tempArray['BM1367 PD C 70']['ST0076']->transferfrom

$tempArray['BM1367 PD B 85']['ST0076']->transferfrom
```

And in-order to compare them

```
(int)$tempArray['BM1367 PD C 70']['ST0076']->transferfrom == (int)$tempArray['BM1367 PD B 85']['ST0076']->transferfrom
```